# javaScript array object in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, listview

I have a question about javaScript array of object:

It looks like below:

```
$scope.todos = [
    {
        face : imagePath,
        what: 'Das',
        who: 'Sophia',
        when: '3:08PM',
        notes: " Description 1",
        linkForward: "#/tab/listView1"
    },
    {
        face : imagePath,
        what: 'Dis',
        who: 'Emma',
        when: '3:08PM',
        notes: " Description 1",
        linkForward: "#/tab/listView2"
    },
    {
        face : imagePath,
        what: 'Dos',
        who: 'Olivia',
        when: '3:08PM',
        notes: " Description 1",
        linkForward: "#/tab/listView3"
    }
];
```

I want to push all this items in a for loop:

It should look like :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    $scope.todos[i].face = 'image Path'
    $scope.todos[i].what= 'image Path'
    $scope.todos[i].who= 'image Path'
    $scope.todos[i].when= 'image Path'
    $scope.todos[i].linkForward= 'image Path'

}
```

But it doesn't work, I want to create this array dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

You should define an array first like `$scope.todos = []` & better way would be like setting array like below.

```
$scope.todos = []
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    $scope.todos.push({
       face: 'image Path', 
       what : 'image Path', 
       who: 'image Path', 
       when: 'image Path', 
       linkForward: 'image Path'
    });
};
```